# How to access and edit globals in Roslyn scripting environment?

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I have an application in which I use the Roslyn scripting engine (namespace `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting`).

What I have right now is this:

```
public static async Task<object> Execute(string code, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (_scriptState == null)
    {
        var options = ScriptOptions.Default;
        options
            .AddReferences(typeof (Type).Assembly,
                typeof (Console).Assembly,
                typeof (IEnumerable<>).Assembly,
                typeof (IQueryable).Assembly)
            .AddImports("System", "System.Numerics", "System.Text", "System.Linq", "System.Collections.Generics",
                "System.Security.Cryptography");
        _scriptState = await CSharpScript.RunAsync(code, options, new MessageGlobal {e = e});
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: set global e (it's not in this variables list, thus it throws null reference)
        _scriptState.GetVariable("e").Value = e;
        _scriptState = await _scriptState.ContinueWithAsync(code);
    }
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_scriptState.ReturnValue?.ToString()) ? _scriptState.ReturnValue : null;
}
```

To make it more clear:
In my app, there is a certain event. User can define what happens when the event occurs with some C# code (this code is being changed frequently). Now the point is - I need to pass event args to the script, so the user can use it in the code. In the same time, I need to keep the engine state, since the user could have defined some variables, which he wants to use the next time.

I already can pass the event args (and refer to it like `e` in the script), but only for the first time (i.e. when the `ScriptState` is null and I create a new one). The next time this or some other script is ran (`ScriptState.ContinueWithAsync`), the event args are the same as in the previous state, because I don't know any way to update them.

How can I reach the `e` global and set it to a new value? I've already tried to access it (as you can see in the code) through the `Variables` list, but it seems that globals aren't kept in the list. At the same time I can't add any variable when running the first script, because the `ScriptVariable` class has an internal constructor. (`ScriptState.Variables.Add( ScriptVariable )`)

Thanks for the help. I hope I've articulated myself, be sure to ask anything in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the original `e` reference:

```
public class Globals
{
    public int E;
}

static void Main()
{
    var globals = new Globals { E = 1 };
    var _scriptState = CSharpScript.RunAsync("System.Console.WriteLine(E)", globals: globals).Result;
    globals.E = 2;
    var x = _scriptState.ContinueWithAsync("System.Console.WriteLine(E)").Result;
}
```